# Trying to ID component

Tags: identification, varistor

Anyone recognize this component or have a NSN or part number?

[image]

On the back it says:

```
0Q6Q  
MEXICO
```

Comment: It looks like a polyfuse.

Comment: A LittleFuse 60V 100mA example: https://www.digikey.hk/zh/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/60R010XU/253192

Comment: If it’s a poly fuse it currently has a reading of 33ohms. From what I read It’s supposed to reset after time.Is that true?

Comment: Datasheet says resistance should be 0.56 to 1.29 Ohms. Looks like your one has failed.

Comment: If it's a polyfuse and you recently (de)soldered it, its resistance will be much higher for several minutes?

Comment: I took a reading when it was still soldered onto the board and after I desoldered, both were 33ohms